# Converting object to Integer equals null

Tags: java, casting

I am trying to convert an object from an object to an integer in java. These are the results I get with the following methods:

```
Object intObject = 50;
intObject: 50
intObject.toString(): 50
Integer.getInteger(intObject.toString()): null
```

I have no idea why I would get a null when converting the string of the object to an integer.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
    final Object temp = mCloudEntity.get(SaveAndLoadManager.TAG_TEST_INT);
    Log.i(TAG, "intObject: " + temp );  
    Log.i(TAG, "intObject.toString(): " + temp.toString()); 
    Log.i(TAG, "Integer.getInteger(intObject.toString()): " + Integer.getInteger(temp.toString()));
```

Comment: Please show some real Java code including your System.out.println's. Sort-of code just confuses us.

Comment: Please show the actual code you are running separate from the output that it produces.

Comment: Why you do not cast your object directly into int?
Integer a = (Integer) intObject;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
// Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer
Integer.parseInt(intObject.toString());
```

instead of

```
// Determines the integer value of the system property with the specified name.
// (Hint: Not what you want)
Integer.getInteger(...)
```

Comment: It would help posting *why* to use this method instead.

Comment: Thanks @LuiggiMendoza, I updated with some snippets of the javadoc

Comment: Check the possible duplicated link to note a proper explanation on the subject. Refer to [What is an acceptable answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118694/182862) points 5, 8, 9, 10 and 11.